# Linebreak after output

Tags: c

When I used the switch statement in the C language and ran it,the output contains two linebreak after it .
I don't know why and just want to get the end result.
Please tell me why and how to deal with it.
Thank you very much !

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
int i;
printf("Please enter an integer：");
scanf("%d",&i);
switch(i){
    case    1:printf("%d---A\n",i); break;
    case    2:printf("%d---B\n",i); break;
    case    3:printf("%d---C\n",i); break;
    case    4:printf("%d---D\n",i); break;
    default : printf("%d---E\n",i); break;
}
return 0;
}
```

when I input 1 will show:

[image]

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It seems you should fix bugs in your code to deal with it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: How can we know what you did wrong in your code if you don't show it to us?

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: Now please tell us *how* you run your program? If you run from inside an IDE perhaps the IDE is adding a newline?

Comment: Your picture ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlKVg.png ) seems to imply that more is going on behind the scenes. Do you have an idea where the "---------------------------" are coming from? Maybe the unwanted empty line is from the same source. I recommende to add the picture to the question again. That is not in conflict with also showing the code as text, as requested in comments.

Comment: To add to @Yunnosch comment about the picture, please take a screenshot of the full output window instead and show it to us.

Comment: Where did all the "--------------" come from? And what is below? Anyway, it's not from your code, it's something in the environment you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does not output a newline:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

Now, if my command shell did not start a new line, the prompt would be

```
Hello worldC:\TEMP>
```

So the shell starts a new line, and the console looks like this:

```
Hello world
C:\TEMP>
```

But if I output a newline in my program, there will be blank line:

```
Hello world

C:\TEMP>
```

The command shell does not know if the final output of the program was a newline or not, without exploring the console output. So for simplicity, it just starts a new line. It's not a bug. If you don't want a blank line, don't output a newline.